# Trying out a simple css3 transition, not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-transitions

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mask">
    <div class="mask-wrapper">
        <div class="front">
            <img src="http://www.biography.com/imported/images/Biography/Images/Profiles/T/Sachin-Tendulkar-20710145-1-402.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <ul>
                <li>Sachin Tendulkar</li>
                <li>Cricketer</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

There's a lot, but, I do css3 transforms like this,

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(720deg);
-o-transform: rotate(720deg);
transform: rotate(720deg);
```

This is not working in IE10 +, works fine in chrome and FX

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/EaU8t/)

Comment: probably answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622441/why-is-backface-visibility-hidden-not-working-in-ie10-when-perspective-is-applie) may help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't support `preserve-3d`. (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround))

However, [this post](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-3d-card.html) offers a workaround where you restyle the 3d transforms to apply the perspective to each side of the flip transition.

### css (still needs some tweaking)

```
#container > div.upper {
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
}

#container:hover > div.lower {
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(0);
}

#container:hover > div.upper {
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -moz-transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    transform:perspective(800px) rotateY(-179.9deg);
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/g8qMB/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use Internet Explorer prefixes (-ms-*): `-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;`