# Internet Explorer Preserve 3D fix

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

The following code works in all browsers except for IE.10.

MSDN website says the following (which I do not understand how to apply):

Note The W3C specification defines a keyword value of preserve-3d for this property, which indicates that flattening is not performed. At this time, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the preserve-3d keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the child element's normal transform.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh673529(v=vs.85).aspx

My code (I'm using CSS selectors for other reasons):

```css
div[class^="flip"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
div[class^="flip"] {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
  width: 313px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
div[class^="flip"] .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
}
div[class^="flip"] .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
div[class^="flip"] .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
div[class^="flip"] .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border: #DDD 1px solid;
}
div[class^="flip"] .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  transform: rotatey(-180deg);
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border: #DDD 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip1">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="face front">Front content</div>
    <div class="face back">Back content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: I had a very good response to a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround

Comment: Did you get this working? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 only partially support 3D transforms. (Older versions of Internet Explorer **do not support this property**).

---

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 'have only partial support' because:

> not supporting the transform-style: preserve-3d property. This
> prevents nesting 3D transformed elements.

---

[further Reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529(v=vs.85).aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property)

This property is suggested to be implemented in the next version of internet explorer, so unfortunately the current IE doesn't really support any 'good' or 'complex' 3D functionality.

Since IE will 'ignore' this property, you may be able to display a message of banner to inform users to use Chrome or Firefox for better experience (it also means you will have to implement less browser hacks to support IE in general).

---

## In answer to your question

> Note The W3C specification defines a keyword value of preserve-3d for
> this property, which indicates that flattening is not performed. At
> this time, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the preserve-3d
> keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent
> element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the
> child element's normal transform.

This is suggesting to apply the transform of the parent manually on the child element. So the 3d transform stated on your parent (`.flip1`) should also be placed on your child element(s) (`.back` and `.front`) as well.

Answer (score 3):

In all versions of IE, `preserve-3d` does not work. In Microsoft Edge, it does.

You can apply a 3D transformation to any element, but if it's parent is 3D transformed as well then the transformation will NOT work; the element will be flattened

so IE10 or IE11 = no fun in 3D.

Comment: This answer was true at the time it was written. Now, IE12 (Edge) does support preserve-3D. In some ways, though, this makes IE even harder to cope with if you want to support older browsers, since it adds yet another way a specific IE browser will render 3D objects.

Comment: @MihneaBelcin BobRay is mistaken; Microsoft Edge is *not* "IE12"; it is a completely different browser. There is no such thing (nor will there ever be) as an IE12.

Comment: cc @BobRay as well

Comment: @TylerH -- You are correct, I should have just written "Microsoft Edge," though I have seen Edge referred to as IE 12 many times.

Comment: no fun in 3D LOL