# Flip animation support in IE

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to implement flip animation. Here is the sample link: http://animista.net/play/basic/flip

and this is the class:

```
.flip-horizontal-bottom {
    -webkit-animation: flip-horizontal-bottom 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.030, 0.515, 0.955) both;
            animation: flip-horizontal-bottom 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.030, 0.515, 0.955) both;
}


/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation flip-horizontal-bottom
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
            transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
            transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
            transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but does not work at all in IE11. What changes would I require to make it work in IE 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their ["How to"](http://animista.net/how-to) notes:

> Also, some of the animations are experimental and may not work as expected in older browsers no matter how you prefix them. Use your own judgement or better yet – consult the super-useful caniuse.com to check for browser support.

Besides, they don't provide the complete code as far as I can tell. They have a `perspective:500px` on their animation stage wrapper (in the demo) which makes it all work, and I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the download example code.

Even after you add it, I doubt it will work in IE, as it lacks support for `transform-style:preserve-3d`, as pointed out in [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335236/internet-explorer-preserve-3d-fix).