# Rotating div elements with CSS transform on IE

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I've got the following CSS hover effect that behaves properly on all browsers but it doesn't on IE. They are three divs, one parent, two children. I want to rotate the parent div in order to show the child's content. you can see the code in [https://jsfiddle.net/drz338r9/11//](https://jsfiddle.net/drz338r9/11/)
I really appreciate any help.

The html code is:

```
 <a class="social" href="" target="_blank">
         <div class="front">
         </div>
         <div class="back">
         </div>
  </a>
```

CSS code is:

```
      .social {
      float: left;
      width: 100px; 
      height: 100px;    
      position: relative;
     -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     transition: transform .25s ease-out;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .social > div {
      width: 100px; height: 100px;
      position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    }
    .social >.front {
      transform:translateZ(40px);
      width: 100px; 
      height: 100px; 
      background: red;
    }
    .social >.back {
      background: #3B5998; 
     -ms-transform: rotateY(-100deg) translateZ(40px);
     transform:rotateY(-100deg) translateZ(40px);
       width: 100px; 
        height: 100px; 
       background: black;
    }
    .social:hover {
      -ms-transform: rotateY(100deg);
      transform: rotateY(100deg);
    }
```

== UPDATE ==

Based on helpful comments, the solution could be found here:https://jsfiddle.net/ohqxnxnn/

Comment: On which version of IE you checking? if it is like <= IE10, use vendor prefix `-ms-` to the css properties.

Comment: yes. I am using IE>=10 and the vendor prefix too. The effects work but in a different way, I don't if i have to use extra rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users said, the problem is that IE doesn't support preserve-3d

To solve it, you need to apply all the transforms on the child elements, the initial ones and the rotated ones

```css
.social {
  float: left;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;    
  position: relative;
}
.social > div {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    transition: transform .25s ease-out;
}
.social > .front {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background: red;
    transform: translateZ(40px);
}
.social:hover .front {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}
.social >.back {
     transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
     width: 100px; 
     height: 100px; 
     background: black;
}

.social:hover .back {
     transform:rotateY(0deg) translateZ(40px);
}
```

```html
<a class="social" href="" target="_blank">
     <div class="front">
     </div>
     <div class="back">
     </div>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research for you and looked at your code. The issue is that IE does not support preserve-3d completely. Luckily, there is a few work arounds here: [CSS3 - 3D Flip Animation - IE10 transform-origin: preserve-3d workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround)

Hope that helps, bud.

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed answer for "CSS3 Solutions for Internet Explorer"  in smashing magazine article you can refer this : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

Also you can include : http://modernizr.com/docs/

and

html5shiv

Hope this will help you,