# Can't get CSS3 transform to work in IE 10/11

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this card opening animation that works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari but I can't seem to get it to work in IE 10/11.

I think it has somthing to do with the

```
 backface-visibility: hidden;
```

but I am not 100% sure.

Any help would be appreciated

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7k9D9/

Comment: Gotta be a duplicate of this :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/11401105/1435655

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in IE:

> At this time, Internet Explorer 10 does not support the preserve-3d
>   keyword. You can work around this by manually applying the parent
>   element's transform to each of the child elements in addition to the
>   child element's normal transform.

Reapply the transforms to the children manually. It's lame, but such is IE.

Original post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15196468/1435655

Comment: I am new to the whole CSS3 transform thing. Do you know how you would do this?

Comment: @user1899891 the quote from Microsoft above explains the fix. I reworded it in my answer, also. Take the transform properties you applied on the parent element and copy them to the children. preserve-3d isn't working in IE, so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: If you're quoting someone else in your answer, it's always a good idea to provide a link back to the source.

Comment: @Spudley apologies, i did in the comments :) I'll update.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my jsfiddle already has that. The problem is that the backface-visibility: hidden; keeps it hidden no matter what its position is.

Comment: @user1899891 I don't think so. You should probably start by copying over your `perspective` rules.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7k9D9/3/
The perspective isn't even needed. This is a version without the perspective or the 3d preserve. The transform was copied over to the child like you said but it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @user1899891 hmm...I didn't pay enough attention, sorry about that. So, as you can see, removing `preserve-3d` makes the behavior the same on all browsers, since IE isn't using it. The trick will be figuring out how to get the same effect. I'll look into it also.