# CSS flip (on click) not working in ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working on a clients team-page. The idea was to show more info (name, profession, etc) after clicking on the image. I got it working with a nice flip-animation. Some browsers (ie8, ie9, ie10) don't animate and just make a simple swap, no problemo. But! IE11 is a creating a problem. The animation seems to work but the back side of the card is not displayed.

I've seen earlier questions like:

- [CSS3 - 3D Flip Animation - IE10 transform-origin: preserve-3d workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474210/css3-3d-flip-animation-ie10-transform-origin-preserve-3d-workaround)
- [backside-visibility not working in IE10 - works fine in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400317/backside-visibility-not-working-in-ie10-works-fine-in-webkit)

But that's IE10 and I'm not the best js/css developer around so don't understand the answers.

Demo can be found here: http://72dpi.nl/klanten/makelaarsland/team/

Code can by found on CodePen: http://codepen.io/jeffreylauwers/pen/HfIFw

HTML:

```
<div class="fake-wrapper"><!-- This 'fake-wrapper' can be deleted -->
    <div class="people">

        <div id="block1" class="block" onclick="changeClass('block1')">
            <div class="front side">
                <img src="img/img_roos-van-schaaijk.jpg" alt="Roos van Schaaijk"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back side">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Rianne van der Tuin</b>
                        <span>Juridisch medewerker</span>
                        <p>Als hij maandags aan de telefoon wat schor klinkt, kan dat komen door de AZ wedstrijd van het weekend ervoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="block2" class="block" onclick="changeClass('block2')">
            <div class="front side">
                <img src="img/img_stijn-van-tol.jpg" alt="Stijn van Tol"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back side">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Rianne van der Tuin</b>
                        <span>Juridisch medewerker</span>
                        <p>Als hij maandags aan de telefoon wat schor klinkt, kan dat komen door de AZ wedstrijd van het weekend ervoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="block3" class="block" onclick="changeClass('block3')">
            <div class="front side">
                <img src="img/img_roos-van-schaaijk.jpg" alt="Roos van Schaaijk"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back side">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Rianne van der Tuin</b>
                        <span>Juridisch medewerker</span>
                        <p>Als hij maandags aan de telefoon wat schor klinkt, kan dat komen door de AZ wedstrijd van het weekend ervoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="block4" class="block" onclick="changeClass('block4')">
            <div class="front side">
                <img src="img/img_stijn-van-tol.jpg" alt="Stijn van Tol"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back side">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Rianne van der Tuin</b>
                        <span>Juridisch medewerker</span>
                        <p>Als hij maandags aan de telefoon wat schor klinkt, kan dat komen door de AZ wedstrijd van het weekend ervoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="block5" class="block" onclick="changeClass('block5')">
            <div class="front side">
                <img src="img/img_roos-van-schaaijk.jpg" alt="Roos van Schaaijk"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back side">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Rianne van der Tuin</b>
                        <span>Juridisch medewerker</span>
                        <p>Als hij maandags aan de telefoon wat schor klinkt, kan dat komen door de AZ wedstrijd van het weekend ervoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="block6" class="block" onclick="changeClass('block6')">
            <div class="front side">
                <img src="img/img_stijn-van-tol.jpg" alt="Stijn van Tol"/>
            </div>
            <div class="back side">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Rianne van der Tuin</b>
                        <span>Juridisch medewerker</span>
                        <p>Als hij maandags aan de telefoon wat schor klinkt, kan dat komen door de AZ wedstrijd van het weekend ervoor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
The Stylesheet for 'Team'
\*------------------------------------*/

/* START: This 'fake-wrapper' can be deleted */
.fake-wrapper{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:51.2em) {
    .fake-wrapper {
        width: 646px;
    }
}
/* END: This 'fake-wrapper' can be deleted */

.people{ 
    margin: 30px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding-bottom : 33.333%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
       -moz-transition: 0.7s;
            transition: 0.7s;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:32em) {
    .block {
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
} 

.rotated{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.block .front{
    z-index: 50;
}
.block .back{
    z-index: 10;
}
.rotated .back{
    z-index: 99;
}

.side{
    position: absolute;  
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* FRONT */
.front{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
}
.front img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.front:hover{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%);
}

/* BACK */
.back{
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%; /* = 100% - 2*10% padding */
    width: 90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
    padding: 10% 5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0d3789;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
       -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
            transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(180deg);
}
.back b{
    display: block;
}
.back span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7333em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.back p{
    font-size: 0.7333em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:32em) {
    .back b{
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
    .back span{
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    .back p{
        font-size: 1em;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
} 

.table{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
function changeClass(visual){
            if(document.getElementById(visual).className == "block")
                document.getElementById(visual).className += " rotated";
            else
                document.getElementById(visual).className = "block";
        }
```

Hope you can help me out.

Kind regards,
Jeffrey

Comment: Have you found a solution?